# Precisely when can/must the two weapon fighting bonus action and attack occur?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, two-weapon-fighting

Complicators: "When", "Take", Composite condition + Extra Attack, Simultaneous events.
Contrast: Immediately after (flurry of blows)

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you’re holding in the other hand.

Reading "When you take the attack action" I start thinking the bonus action must be used at the same time as the attack action is taken, which seems to be when you use the first/only attack it allows you, but once you can make multiple attacks with the action, the composite condition makes that make less sense.

For what I think the rule is, I would prefer to say something like "When you use the attack action to make an attack with a light melee weapon". Because that is right, isn't it? At any point during the execution of the attack action, when you use that action to make an attack with a weapon that meets the criteria, you can at the same time make an attack, as a bonus action, with a weapon in your other hand that meets the same criteria.

Questions remaining: must you use the bonus action before resolving the attack that enables you to take it, and if so, in what order do the attacks resolve?

To me the wording says you attack with both weapons at the same time, you take the bonus action to make that happen when you make the attack, not after seeing how the attack turns out, and the attacks (one part of an attack action, one a bonus action) are simultaneous, so the player should get to choose the order in which to resolve them.

Is this RAW / how is RAW different from this? (And is RAI known to differ from RAW?)

(I realised just now that "take" also makes me uncertain about "immediately after" for flurry of blows, but I seem to remember from a clarification that "immediately after you take the attack action" means the moment when no part of the attack action has yet to be executed)